# sqlite xcode query clause

Tags: xcode, sqlite

i have some strange problem with my query on sqlite. 
When i have values for the firstvar between 30000 and 100000 my query doesn't return anything. but when the var is lower than 30000 and bigger than 100000 it does. it's the same in my xcode app as in sqlite browser.

```
SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE price > firstvar AND price < secondvar
```

here is some example data: 
http://www.purespain.com/example%20data.png

so when i perform the query for example

```
    SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE price > 40000 AND price < 300000
```

i have no ouput while there are a lot of offers with a price  (prijs) that should match the criteria.

when i perform for example

```
  SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE price > 140000 AND price < 300000
```

or          SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE price > 0 AND price < 300000

then i have correct results

the code for executing the query is:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)selectOffersWithOndergrens:(int)ondergrens andBovengrens:(int)bovengrens andSoort:(NSString *)soort{

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask , YES);
NSString *docpath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
dbPathString = [docpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"puurspanje.db"];

Offers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Get all newsitems from the sqlite database
sqlite3_stmt *get_offers_stmt;
NSString *querysql = [[NSString alloc]init];
if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &puurspanjeDB)==SQLITE_OK){
    [Offers removeAllObjects];

    if (![soort isEqual: @"alle"]){
        querysql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE prijs > %d AND prijs < %d AND soort = (SELECT TYPE_ID FROM TYPES WHERE NAME LIKE '%@' )", ondergrens, bovengrens, soort];
    }else{
        querysql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM OFFERS WHERE prijs > %d AND prijs < %d", ondergrens, bovengrens];

    }

    const char* query_sql = [querysql UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare(puurspanjeDB, query_sql, -1, &get_offers_stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(get_offers_stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *listing_ID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 1)];
            NSString *titel = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char * )sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 2)];
            NSString *omschrijving = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char * )sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 3)];
            NSString *prijs = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char * )sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 4)];
            NSString *referentie = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 5)];
            NSString *slaapkamer = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 6)];
            NSString *verdiep = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 7)];
            NSString *badkamers = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 8)];
            NSString *woonoppv = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 9)];
            NSString *perceeloppv = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 10)];
            NSString *kenmerken = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 11)];
            NSString *buurtkenmerken = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 12)];
            NSString *indeling = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 13)];
            NSString *hypotheek = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 14)];
            NSString *soort = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(get_offers_stmt, 15)];



            Offer *offer = [[Offer alloc]initWithListing_ID:listing_ID andTitel:titel andOmschrijving:omschrijving andPrijs:prijs andReferentie:referentie andSlaapkamers:slaapkamer andVerdiep:verdiep andBadkamers:badkamers andWoonoppv:woonoppv andPerceeloppv:perceeloppv andKenmerken:kenmerken andBuurtKenmerken:buurtkenmerken andIndeling:indeling andHypotheek:hypotheek andSoort:soort];
            [Offers addObject:offer];
        }
    }
}
return Offers;
```

}

I have no idea what the reason could be. Any help is appreciated.

Jonas

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Show example data and expected and actual output.

Comment: Read the [FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: i added some info in my topic. i hope the problem is clear now

Comment: I don't see a `price` column?

Comment: price = prijs my original query is select* from offers where prijs > 40000 < 300000 but i putted in english here

Comment: Show the *actual* code that submits the query.

Comment: i added the code, but i don't think the problem is in the code because when i perform the query in sqlite database browser (program for mac to execute query's on sqlite databases) it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason was that i choose text as datatype and not numeric and because there were spaces in the text the result's were not showing ok.